# waiting for a service to be advertised?

Tags: ros, household-objects-database, rosservice, tabletop-object-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I'm working with tabletop_object_detector and household_objects_database
I typed these commands in my terminal :

```
 roscore
 rosmake tabletop_object_detector
 rosmake household_objects_database
 rospack find tabletop_object_detector
 roscd tabletop_object_detector
 roslaunch tabletop_object_detector tabletop_object_recognition.launch
```

after the last command , the terminal tells me that :

- INFO] [1363624742.520172331]: waitForService: Service [/objects_database_node/get_model_mesh] has not been advertised, waiting...

and when I tried to call these service , It told me that it's not found !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58451/waiting-for-a-service-to-be-advertised-!/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will also need to launch household_objects_database/launch/objects_database_local_server.launch with a properly populated .yaml file with the right connection parameters for your local PostgreSQL server.

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-21**:
when I type this command >> It tells me that :
[household_objects_database/launch/objects_database_local_server.launch] does not exist. please specify a package and launch file

**Comment by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) on 2013-03-22**:
package: household_objects_database. Launch file: objects_database_local_server.launch

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-22**:
Still , having the same error !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check rxgraph to make sure that your nodes are subscribing to the correct service topics.

---

Originally posted by [Rookdroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/4073/rookdroid/) with karma: 76 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-21**:
The output of ( rxgraph)  only contains :
rosout , tabletop_object_recognition nodes :(

Does this mean that household_objects_database doesn't work ??